# Is there a callback for post Craft 3 CMS installation I can use?

Tags: craft3, installation, modules

I was hoping to have my module create a few fields, sections, and entries after the Craft 3 CMS has completed it's installation.

Is there a callback I can listen to that triggers after the CMS is installed? Or maybe there's a `onAfterInstall` equivalent I can run?

I've been poking around the [InstallController](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/InstallController.php), but I'm really not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can't you just create a normal migration and run it? Plugins have such an ability but modules not by default. That's why I would just create a normal migration

Comment: Thanks Robin. I've taken a good look in content migration and was ready to create a detailed and complex migration. Then Craft's 3.1 'Project Config' was announced. This will do everything and more on it's release. https://craftcms.com/support/craft-3-1-dev-preview-notes